# Why MySQL and UTF-8 doesn't recognize encoding?

Tags: mysql, encoding, pdo

I connected to database with `PDO` and state `"SET NAMES":`

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gs', 'root','', array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT=>true,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'
));
```

My database is set for `"utf8_general_ci"`. And, when I insert records from my site (using POST), it works. But, when I insert records using PHPMyAdmin (or Admin), **encoding fails**.

Inserting using `INSERT` queries gives me good encoding on the site, but in the database,It has all weird symbols.

What can I do to have proper encoded symbols everywhere?

Comment: Isn't this a phpMyAdmin issue then? :)

Comment: It doesn't seem this way, both phpMyAdmin and Adminer returns wrong coding, while other databases (eg. from WordPress) are fine.

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Comment: I have 5.3.1, came with XAMPP.

Comment: 1) Does the problem replicate in different browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox, ...)? 2) Could you check `$cfg['DefaultCharset']`, `$cfg['DefaultLang']` and `$cfg['DefaultConnectionCollation']` in `xampp/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`? Are they set to `utf8`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the "case", but I can't see... how ;) I just coded everything again (since I changed the design drastically), using almost the same elements, and now it works great.